# In Groovy, Is there any way to safely index into a Collection similar to the safe navigation operator?

Tags: groovy

This will safely return null without throwing any exceptions

```
obj?.prop1?.prop2
```

How can I do that for collections, where it won't throw an index out of bounds exception?

```
myarray[400]  //how do I make it return null if myarray.size() < 400
```

Is there such an operator for Collections?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

That's the default behavior with all collections except arrays in groovy.

```
assert [1,2,3,4][5] == null
def test = new ArrayList()
assert test[100] == null
assert [1:"one", 2:"two"][3] == null
```

If you've got an array, cast it to a list.

```
def realArray = new Object[4]
realArray[100] // throws exception
(realArray as List)[100] // null
```

You can string list and map indexes together with the `?` operator in the same way as with properties:

```
def myList = [[name: 'foo'], [name: 'bar']]
assert myList[0]?.name == 'foo'
assert myList[1]?.name == 'bar'
assert myList[2]?.name == null
```

Comment: But watch out for negative indices which will cause an exception, ie: `def a = [] ; println a[ -1 ]` throws a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: @tim_yates any idea why? seems rather inconsistent.

Comment: an addendum for any groovy noobs like my looking for this, if you need to do map access for variable key names you can use this syntax to take advantage of null-safe operator: `mymap = null` `keyName = "WTF"` `mymap?."$keyName"`

Comment: Please note, that: `test[100]` returns `null`, **BUT** `test.get(100)` throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. The same for `test?.get(100)`

Answer (score -1):

You can use get() instead:

```
myarray?.get(400)
```

Comment: This throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if the index is indeed out of bounds, which is actually worse than the current behavior for `myarray[400]` which returns `null`.

Comment: Actually, you're right. However myarray?.getAt(400) will return null if out of bounds.

Comment: For what version of Groovy? I've tested with 2.4.13, 2.4.6, 2.0.0, and 1.7.8.

Comment: This is not correct. 
The `?` could only help if `myarray` is null. 
If `myarray` is null then calculation of the expression terminates.
Otherwise it continuous and tries to access to 400th item which is not exists. And we will get an exception.